# the efficient query for products have two keywords

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

Suppose I have the following table

ProductValue(ID,ProductID,Value)

I want to get the top 100 products that exist records with values containing "one" and "two"

I wrote the following queries but I want to find a more efficient query

```
Select Top 100 ProductID From (
SELECT [ProductID]
  FROM [ProductValue]
  where [Value] like '%One%'
  intersect
SELECT [ProductID]
  FROM [ProductValue]
  where [Value] like '%Two%') g
```

the following query is more efficient

```
 Select Top 100 ProductID From [ProductValue] Where 
    ProductID in ( Select ProductID From [ProductValue] Where [Value] like '%One%' ) 
    and ProductID in ( Select ProductID From [ProductValue] Where [Value] like '%Two%' )
    group by ProductID
```

Which query is more optimal than the queries above?

Comment: To call this "top 100" is a bit inadequate here, because we are not looking for the top 100 by some ranking, but for mere arbitrary 100 that match the conditions.

Comment: i think you can't beat: select top 100 * from productvalue where value like '%One%' and value like '%Two%'

Comment: @siggemannen, no your query does not my goal, "one" is in a record, and "two" is in another record

Comment: Oh OK. It's not clear since you don't give any sample data. I thought product table was unique per productid :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rather doubt that the second query is more efficient than the first one. And I don't know whether the follwing queries are going to be more efficient, either. They are just two more options:

```
select top(100) [ProductID]
from [ProductValue]
where [Value] like '%One%' or [Value] like '%Two%'
group by [ProductID]
having max(case when [Value] like '%One%' then 1 else 0 end) = 1
   and max(case when [Value] like '%Two%' then 1 else 0 end) = 1;
```

The where clause is not really needed, but may speeed up the query.

If there exists a product table, as the column name [ProductID] promises, I'd probably go with

```
select top(100) [ProductID]
from [Product]
where [ProductID] in (select [ProductID] from [ProductValue] where [Value] like '%One%')
  and [ProductID] in (select [ProductID] from [ProductValue] where [Value] like '%Two%');
```

This last query would be the best option, if it were not about searching with `LIKE '%something%'` which does not benefit from an index. In another case where we might be looking for exact matches of 'One' and 'Two' it could loop through the products, quickly look up the values without aggregation and stop at the 100th match.